# Different ways how to deal with package reference in csproj

Tags: c#, .net-core, csproj

Till now, I was always using attributes to control asset dependency for `PackageReference` (first example). Recently, after using NuGet package manager (in VS), I ended up with quite different XML though.

Both are controlling same thing, could anyone help me understanding difference and need of having two ways how to control similar thing?

[Additions to the csproj format for .NET Core > PackageReference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/csproj#packagereference)

```
<PackageReference Include="Contoso.Utility.UsefulStuff" Version="3.6.0" PrivateAssets="..." IncludeAssets="..." ExcludeAssets="..." />
```

[Package references (PackageReference) in project files > Controlling dependency assets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files#controlling-dependency-assets):

```
<PackageReference Include="Contoso.Utility.UsefulStuff" Version="3.6.0">
    <IncludeAssets>...</IncludeAssets>
    <ExcludeAssets>...</ExcludeAssets>
    <PrivateAssets>...</PrivateAssets>
</PackageReference>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are functionally equivalent. With one exception, using attributes on the `<PackageReference>` element is a shortcut for having a nested elements by the same name. The exception is the `Include` attribute, which cannot be a nested element.

So, Visual Studio, MSBuild, NuGet, etc. will treat these the the same:

```
<PackageReference Include="Contoso.Utility.UsefulStuff" Version="3.6.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Contoso.Utility.UsefulStuff">
  <Version>3.6.0</Version>
</PackageReference>
```

Same goes for the other attributes like "ExcludeAsset".

> after using NuGet package manager (in VS), I ended up with quite different XML though.

The NuGet package manager in VS isn't honoring the original format of the document when it makes modifications to your `<PackageReference>`'s. It probably NuGet is getting the *interpreted* result of the .csproj file, not the raw XML, so it doesn't know whether you were using attributes or nested elements.